# Not getting record from old moodle to new moodle

Tags: moodle

I am facing a problem. I have upgraded my moodle database from 1.9 to 2.7.1. After upgraded from old to new version, some of table structure are changed. I am not getting user who enrolled in courses after upgrade. Please help me to sought it out.

Comment: Check what enrolment plugin was used for the missing users.

Comment: Russell England do u know any plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading Moodle from a version to a newer one, you should always do it step by step.
This means, you should avoid jumping major versions between yours and the newest one.

In your case, this is even more complicated, because Moodle 1.x is very different from Moodle 2.x.
You must first upgrade your Moodle 1.9 to Moodle 2.0.x.

Then, after checking that everything's fine, upgrade your Moodle 2.0.x to 2.1.x.
Repeat the same for every major version (2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6 and then 2.7).

Doing this, you avoid crashing your database because of major modifications.

Check out the official doc for more informations about it : https://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Upgrading_to_Moodle_2.0

Comment: What is the enrolment method used for those users ? (manual, self, ldap, ...)

Comment: I have used self enrollment

Comment: Were the self-enrolment methods activated in your courses after upgrading ?